# How to use "While()" in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-2.x

Hi all my code below allows me to extract some specific informations from the data and i would like that someone helps me to write this more properly by using a while so i can do this for many lines now i only have two lines ( data ) i'm beginner so if someone can help please explain so i can learn and not just copy and paste =)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import re 

tableau = []

data = "00:02:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxx@x.fr mid:6499"

result1 = {}
i = re.findall(r"^.[^\ ]*", data ) 
j = re.findall(r"\d+$", data ) 
k = re.findall(r"O:[^\ ]*", data ) 
r = re.findall(r"R:[^\ ]*", data )

result1 = {'Heure':i,'MID':j,'Source':k,'Destination':r} 

data = "00:03:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxxx@xxxxx.fr mid:6599"

result2 = {}
i = re.findall(r"^.[^\ ]*", data ) 
j = re.findall(r"\d+$", data ) 
k = re.findall(r"O:[^\ ]*", data ) 
r = re.findall(r"R:[^\ ]*", data )

result2 = {'Heure':i,'MID':j,'Source':k,'Destination':r} 

tableau.append(result1)
tableau.append(result2)

print tableau
```

Comment: `while` is a Python keyword, there's no "`While()`" function. (Also, you probably want a `for` loop here, as you're iterating over a particular set of data.)

Comment: I don't think 'while' is what you want. As I understand, in general you will have 'data' as a list of strings. In such case you'd use 'for..in..' loop

Comment: Clarify your question - it's not clear what you'd like to loop through.

Comment: Some tips: organise your data into a list; iterate over the list using a for loop; extract the result and append it to the tableau for each iteration. Not much has to be changed, so I'm sure you'll be able to work it out. There are plenty of online tutorials if you're having trouble.

Comment: FWIW, the lines `result1 = {}` and `result2 = {}` are unnecessary.

Comment: yeah you're right after i posted the question i figured out that for loop would be better, well to clarify my question.. I have a file with many lines similar to data ( in my code ) and i want to extract the ( i,j,k,r ) and put them in a table so since i just started i applied this in one line then two... and i think that if i have a for loop i'll be able to do this in the whole file

Comment: @JamesH -- Yes, the loop will be fine.  In fact, you can get the lines from the fileobject (after you `open` it) using `for line in fileobject: ...`

Comment: Seriously - get a Python tutorial. It's the easiest way to learn.

Comment: @migilson i will try that now ;) hope i'll succeed !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually done better with a [`for` loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
data1 = "00:02:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxx@x.fr mid:6499"
data2 = "00:03:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxxx@xxxxx.fr mid:6599"
data_list = [ data1, data2 ] #store the data in a list so we can iterate over it
tableau = [] #create a list to hold our output
for data in data_list:  #iterate over the list, getting 1 "data" at a time
    #extract info we want
    i = re.findall(r"^.[^\ ]*", data ) 
    j = re.findall(r"\d+$", data ) 
    k = re.findall(r"O:[^\ ]*", data ) 
    r = re.findall(r"R:[^\ ]*", data )

    #create dictionary and append it to tableau
    tableau.append({'Heure':i,'MID':j,'Source':k,'Destination':r})
```

More advanced users would probably use a function here which takes the string as input and returns a dictionary of the desired data:

```
def extract(data):
    i = re.findall(r"^.[^\ ]*", data ) 
    j = re.findall(r"\d+$", data ) 
    k = re.findall(r"O:[^\ ]*", data ) 
    r = re.findall(r"R:[^\ ]*", data )
    return {'Heure':i,'MID':j,'Source':k,'Destination':r}
```

now you can use this in a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
tableau = [extract(data) for data in data_list]
```

From the comments, it looks like you're getting the lines of data from a file.  That's even better (Who wants to type all those strings?).  Now we can shorten this to:

```
with open('filename') as fin:
    tableau = [extract(data) for data in fin]
```

using `with` introduces another python structure -- (the context manager).  That's a little more complex, but it's the prefered way to open a file.  for file objects, it's functionally equivalent to:

```
fin = open('filename')
tableau = ...
fin.close()
```

Comment: This is a fine approach to the problem, However - I would recommend using the regular expression in my answer as it is much faster.

Comment: yeah but with i can't use it in python 2.6 : /

Comment: Sure -- I didn't even look at the regex's.  Ultimately, I want OP to learn something about *python*.  And you have a mutable default argument (which is fine with your function, but probably not a good idea if OP takes that idiom and uses it everywhere)

Answer (score 3):

Here. This parses your data in a much more efficient method, it uses a function that you can just feed a list of data too. If you want to turn this into a generator it is also very easy.

```
import re

def parser(data):
    result = []
    for p in data:
        ms = re.match(r'(\S+).*?(O:\S+).*(R:\S+).*mid:(\d+)', p)
        if not ms:
            continue
        result.append({'Heure':ms.group(1), 'Source':ms.group(2), 'Destination':ms.group(3), 'MID':ms.group(4)})
    return result


data = ["00:02:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxx@x.fr mid:6499",
        "00:03:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxxx@xxxxx.fr mid:6599"]

print parser(data)
```

Results:

```
>>> 
[{'Source': 'O:NVS:FAXG3/', 'Destination': 'R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxx@x.fr', 'Heure': '00:02:12.935', 'MID': '6499'},
{'Source': 'O:NVS:FAXG3/', 'Destination': 'R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxxx@xxxxx.fr', 'Heure': '00:03:12.935', 'MID': '6599'}]
```

---

As a generator:

```
import re

def parser(data):
    for p in data:
        ms = re.match(r'(\S+).*?(O:\S+).*(R:\S+).*mid:(\d+)', p)
        if not ms:
            continue
        yield {'Heure':ms.group(1), 'Source':ms.group(2), 'Destination':ms.group(3), 'MID':ms.group(4)}       

data = ["00:02:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxx@x.fr mid:6499",
        "00:03:12.935 mta         Messages       I Doc O:NVS:FAXG3/ R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxxx@xxxxx.fr mid:6599"]

for r in parser(data):
    print r
```

Results:

```
>>> 
{'Source': 'O:NVS:FAXG3/', 'Destination': 'R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxx@x.fr', 'Heure': '00:02:12.935', 'MID': '6499'}
{'Source': 'O:NVS:FAXG3/', 'Destination': 'R:NVS:SMTP.0/xxxxx@xxxxx.fr', 'Heure': '00:03:12.935', 'MID': '6599'}
```

---

Using [@mgilsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060507/1561176) idea with my regex:

```
def extract(data):
    ms = re.match(r'(\S+).*?(O:\S+).*(R:\S+).*mid:(\d+)', data)
    if not ms:
        raise Exception('Could not extract data')
    return {'Heure':ms.group(1), 'Source':ms.group(2), 'Destination':ms.group(3), 'MID':ms.group(4)}

tableau = [extract(data) for data in data_list]
```

Comment: Thank you inbar rose for correcting my regex it's much better this way !

Comment: I fixed the return dictionary. I made a mistake on the ms groups. Check my edit.

Comment: I liked the way you write the REGEX, i'm not very familiar with it, can you tell me how would you write a re to extract what's after i've tried (O:NVS:\S+) but it returns all the value (O:NVS:FAXG3) i would like it to return only FAXG3 and same thing with (R:NVS:\S+) i'd like it to return only the xxxx@x.fr 
well briefly the goal is to get the Type of the origin message and it's sender and the type of the destination message and it's destination, am i clear enough ?

Comment: You are welcome to ask a new question about how to make a more efficient regular expression, or you can try yourself. Consult the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) or use [this site](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) as a good place to start.

Comment: Okay i will try by myself and if i don't succeed i'll ask a question, thank you for your time anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think while is the best way to do what you are expecting. maybe you can use

```
for data in dataArray:
```

Where the dataArray contain your data string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wooble for inspiring this `While` function and example. The idea got me thinking how to do it.

```
>>> def While(function, *args, **kwargs):
    while function(*args, **kwargs): pass


>>> def unstack(array):
    print(array.pop())
    return array

>>> While(unstack, ['world!', 'there', 'Hello'])
Hello
there
world!

>>> def fib(state):
    state.append(sum(state))
    print(state.pop(0))
    return state[0] < 1000

>>> While(fib, [0, 1])
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
>>>
```

Generators are rather nice too, so a `WhileGenerator` was created as well to satisfy my curiosity.

```
>>> def WhileGenerator(function, *args, **kwargs):
    iterator = iter(function(*args, **kwargs))
    while next(iterator):
        yield next(iterator)


>>> import operator, functools, itertools
>>> for value in WhileGenerator(lambda a, b: functools.reduce(operator.add,
        itertools.zip_longest(a, b)),
        (True, True, True, False),
        'Hello there world!'.split()):
    print(value)


Hello
there
world!
>>> def fib_gen(state, limit):
    while True:
        yield state[0] < limit
        state.append(sum(state))
        yield state.pop(0)


>>> for value in WhileGenerator(fib_gen, [0, 1], 1000):
    print(value)


0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
>>>
```